# How to parse JSON values in its correct type in Go?

Tags: go

I'm processing events from an JSON API in Go but unfortunately every value returned is encapsulated as string.

The JSON events coming form that API look somewhat as the following:

```
[
  {
    "id": "283702",
    "price": "59.99",
    "time": "1508813904",
    "type": "some_update"
  },
  {
    "id": "283701",
    "price": "17.50",
    "time": "1508813858",
    "type": "some_update"
  }
]
```

Now my code to parse these evens looks like the following example:

```
type event []struct {
    ID string    `json:"id"`
    Price string `json:"price"`
    Time string  `json:"time"`
    Type string  `json:"type"`
}

// Requesting and parsing events here ...

id, err := strconv.ParseInt(event.ID, 0, 64)
if err != nil {
    return err
}

price, err := strconv.ParseFloat(event.Price, 64)
if err != nil {
    return err
}

timestamp, err := strconv.ParseInt(event.Time, 0, 64)
if err != nil {
    return err
}

datetime := time.Unix(timestamp, 0).UTC()
```

Now this code is a bit repetitive but basically I'm parsing the `id`, `price` and `time` and then I'm converting the timestamp to a time value.

Now my question, can I convert the values at the same time as parsing the JSON response? Or is there no way around this and I need to do the type conversion later as shown in this example?

Comment: "Now my question, can I convert the values at the same time as parsing the JSON response." Yes. Please take a look at the package documentation, the internet or just _try_ using `int`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have to use `string` type. The `encoding/json` package can handle the conversion from string to *string*, *floating point*, *integer*, or *boolean* types by using the ["string" option](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal) in the tags.

As an example, try:

```
type event []struct {
    ID    uint64  `json:"id,string"`
    Price float64 `json:"price,string"`
    Time  int64   `json:"time,string"`
    Type  string  `json:"type"`
}
```

Comment: Wow. This is so much better 